# Getting "Failed to determine a suitable driver class" when trying to generate Angular client code

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, maven

Following [this](https://code.danielfrak.com/generate-client-code-from-spring-boot-using-maven/) tutorial I tried to create my Angular client by calling:

```
mvn clean verify -P angular
```

which gives me the following error:

```
Consider the following:
        If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
        If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).
```

This makes sense, I thought, because I am not even telling Spring Boot which profile I want to use so

```
mvn clean verify -P angular -Dspring.profiles.active=local
```

was supposed to help, or, rather the whole things:

```
JDBC_DATABASE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/database;JDBC_DATABASE_USERNAME=postgres;JDBC_DATABASE_PASSWORD=root mvn clean verify -P angular -Dspring.profiles.active=local
```

However, I am still getting the error.

Also, I see this in the log:

```
my.spring.Application: No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
```

What am I missing?

---

**Please Note:** These are the exact run and environment configs I am using during development.

---

**Update:**

I also added

```xml
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

to the **pom.xml** which is where the **application-local.properties** file is located.

Comment: I am using a PostgreSQL database. The second line states "_If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active)._" which is, however, what I am doing with `-Dspring.profile.activate=local`

Comment: @Jens or do I have to add the `resources/` folder manually to the classpath in this case as well?

Comment: You have to add the jar containing the db driver class as a dependency to your project

Comment: @Jens Not sure if I understand or know how. Do I have to add the jar file which gets executed as its own dependency?

Comment: https://mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-spring-data-jpa-postgresql/

Comment: @Jens That's just how you configure PostreSQL for a Spring application.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so, this setting the resource directory was **not** the issue. The following can be removed:

```
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

The issue was the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` which has to be configured. I don't know if there is an easier way but for now it works:

I had to set the environment variables and also the profile for the plugin directly in the **pom.xml** so, however provides a better answer than this will ge accepted.

For now my solution looks like this:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>pre-integration-test</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>start</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>post-integration-test</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>stop</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <arguments>
            <argument>--server.port=${tomcat.http.port}</argument>
            <!-- Set the profile like this -->
            <argument>--spring.profiles.active=local</argument>
        </arguments>
        <!-- Added these environment variables -->
        <environmentVariables>
            <JDBC_DATABASE_URL>jdbc:postgresql://localhost/mydatabase</JDBC_DATABASE_URL>
            <JDBC_DATABASE_USERNAME>postgres</JDBC_DATABASE_USERNAME>
            <JDBC_DATABASE_PASSWORD>root</JDBC_DATABASE_PASSWORD>
        </environmentVariables>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```